# npm run production not working after hosting the application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, production

When I run npm production on my localhost, everything works good but after hosting the application I try to run the same command (`npm run prod` or `npm run production`), I get always the same error message.

- npm version: 6.10.3
- webpack version: webpack@3.12.0

// node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

```js
/**
 * As our first step, we'll pull in the user's webpack.mix.js
 * file. Based on what the user requests in that file,
 * a generic config object will be constructed for us.
 */

require('../src/index');
require(Mix.paths.mix());

/**
 * Just in case the user needs to hook into this point
 * in the build process, we'll make an announcement.
 */

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

/**
 * Now that we know which build tasks are required by the
 * user, we can dynamically create a configuration object
 * for Webpack. And that's all there is to it. Simple!
 */

let WebpackConfig = require('../src/builder/WebpackConfig');

module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();
```

//package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aos": "^2.3.4",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.6.1",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
        "vue-passport": "^1.0.13",
        "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.8",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^1.6.4",
        "vue-top-progress": "^0.7.0",
        "vuetify": "^1.5.18",
        "webpack": "^3.12.0"
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T13_38_27_403Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after hosting the application"? Where do you run the command?

Comment: thanks for your comment  i meant  when i run command on the server cloud ( digitalocean ) , but now i tried to run " npm run production " on localhost then i pushed the changes to degitalocean and the message  "You are running Vue in development mode...."  has disappeared on mozilla firefox but not in google chrome  maybe this have a relation with cookies or something ?!

Comment: Try to remove your cache with CTRL+F5?

Comment: it's work ! thank you a lot guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to run a node server separately for your vueis to work, all you need to do is to build it and include it into your laravel application like any other JavaScript file, and if you want to be involved in server side rendering you can use the laravel server side library for such or look into phpv8 engine

Comment: A dev server is useful for development. Nevertheless, his `production` scripts is actually used to build the app. Also, Laravel Mix != Laravel.

Comment: so , i need to run "npm run production" on my localhost then i push changes to the hoster side ?

Comment: yea, Something like that,  so you just simply have to replace the js file there,  which most times defaults to app.js

Comment: i tried to do that.. and the message "You are running Vue in development mode...." has disappeared on mozilla firefox but not in google chrome maybe this have a relation with cookies or something ?!

Comment: what is your cache like?

Comment: then also consider "npm run prod" instead of  "npm run production" just incase it's not setting the right node env

Comment: yeh i tries npm run prod too but same problem , cache in google chrome console ?

Comment: i juste remove cache with CTRL+F5 as  Jérémie L suggest :D

Answer (score 0):

Thats a problem with version of laravel mix so update it with below commands

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest --save-dev
```

then

```
npm install
```